# Space increased in MyISAM table after change column type from INT to SMALLINT and TINYINT

Tags: mysql, myisam, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to reduce the space occupied by my DB tables and optimize the performance of my system. I'm interested to optimize specially some MyISAM table with large amount of data.
So I changed the column type as follow:
- from INT(11) to BIT(1) or TINYINT(3) or SMALLINT(6) or MEDIUMINT(9)
- from VARCHAR(...) to CHAR(x), with x the smallest number of characters useful

But the result was unexpected.
I ran the following query before and after my changes:

> SELECT 
>       table_name AS "Table", 
>       round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) "Size in MB"  FROM information_schema.TABLES  WHERE table_schema =
>   "my_schema"
>       AND table_name = "my_table";

Results:
- BEFORE 558 Mb
- AFTER 673,96 Mb

The space is increased. Why?

**Edit:**
The problem was CHAR conversion. In my case VARCHAR occupies less space because the fields are not of fixed dimension, so fixed CHAR fields need more space.
With VARCHAR my table occupies 444 Mb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `INT` changes should have helped.

The `VARCHAR` changes should have hurt.

Do not use `CHAR` unless you (1) the data is constant length, and (2) the `CHARACTER SET` is appropriate.

`VARCHAR` is implemented as 1 or 2 bytes of length, plus only as many bytes as are needed for each string.

`CHAR(N)` always occupies M*N bytes:  M bytes/character depends on the charset:  ascii/latin1: 1; utf8: 3, utf8mb4: 4.

There are a very few cases where `CHAR` is actually better than `VARCHAR`.  Here are some:

```
country_code CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii,
md5 CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET ascii, -- packing into BINARY(16) would be tighter
zip_code CHAR(5) CHARACTER SET ascii, -- MEDIUMINT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL would be tighter
uuid CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET ascii, -- Could be packed into BINARY(16)
```

Hmmm... That's all I can think of at the moment.

And, no, MyISAM does *not* benefit from "FIXED" instead of "DYNAMIC", except in rare cases.  Since `VARCHAR` is smaller, there is less I/O; I/O is the *main* cost of dealing with data.

Next:  Forget about MyISAM and move up to InnoDB.

Comment: PS:  Don't use `VARCHAR(n)` when `n` is the minimum; tomorrow you will get a longer string.  So give yourself _some_ slack.

Comment: I use MyISAM because I have to delete and insert many rows every day. MyISAM tables are the fact tables of a Data Warehouse and are very large. With InnoDB the delete operation was too expensive. My goal is to reduce the time of delete and insert in my table.

Comment: If you are deleting "old" data, then partitioning is even faster -- virtually instantaneous.  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Comment: I don't have to delete "old" data, but recent data that have to be updated. So I don't know if partitioning is useful in this case.

Comment: Partitioning probably won't help.  Fix what you can from this thread.  Then, if you want to, open another thread to discuss DW issues.  Include data size, ingestion speed, update/delete issues, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, etc.